# C++, copy constructor confusion

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, gcc-warning

say I created a custom Array class and have following constructor:

```
    Array::Array(size_t size)
    {
      mySize = size;
      //myData is of type int*
      myData = new int[mySize]; // this stuff is allocated on a heap
    }
```

To my knowledge, a default copy constructor in this case  would be implemented like that:

```
    Array::Array(Array& a)
    {
      mySize = a.mySize;
      myData = a.myData; //points to the same memory on the heap
    }
```

Finally, say I have following code in my main.cpp file

```
     int main()
     {
       Array a(1);
       Array b(a); //copy constructor is invoked
     }
```

What I expected to be was a memory leak due to deletion of myData pointers to the free store memory, BUT I have following runtime error :

```
*** glibc detected *** ./main.out: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x086ad008 ***
```

WHY? It seems that ~Array() somehow auto frees memory allocated on a heap - but this is very counter intuitive to me. Maybe I am missing something?

UPDATE:

```
      class Array{
         private:
           size_t mySize;
           int *myData;
           ...
```

UPDATE 2:

main.cpp:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "array.h"

   int main()
   {
     Array a(1);
     Array b(a);
   }
```

array.h:

```
   #ifndef ARRAY_H_
   #define ARRAY_H_
   #include <stddef.h>
   class Array{
   private:
       size_t mySize;
       int *myData;
   public:
       Array(size_t size);
       ~Array();
       void set(int i,int val);
       int get(int i);
       size_t getSize();
   };
   #endif
```

array.cpp:

```
   #include "array.h"

   Array::Array(size_t size)
   {
     mySize = size;
     myData = new int[mySize];
   }

   Array::~Array()
   {
     delete[] myData;
   }

   void Array::set(int i, int val)
   {
     if(i>=0 && i<mySize)
       myData[i] = val;
   }

   int Array::get(int i)
   {
     if(i>=0 && i<mySize)
       return myData[i];
     else return -1;
   }
   size_t Array::getSize()
   {
     return mySize;
   }
```

Comment: Are you saying your destructor does not free the memory? If so, it is hard to understand the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: I'm saying that destructor presumably frees memory that is pointed to a heap, which it shouldn't be...at lease to my little knowledge.

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't be.  You're living in an alternate universe.

Comment: The destructor will do no such thing unless you tell it so. Can you post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Could you post the entire class?  Did you define an assignment operator?  a destructor?  a custom `delete` implementation?  Does `Array` subclass anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in your destructor you have

```
 Array::~Array(void)
 {
      delete [] myData; //points to the same memory on the heap
 }
```

The problem is double free

Example:

```
int main()
{
       Array a(1);  // here a.myData = 0x12345678
       Array b(a); //copy constructor is invoked // here b.myData = 0x12345678

       // pop  stack (call destroy of object)
       // delete b.myData
       // delete a.myData already delete
}
```

**Double free**

**EDIT:**
For your copy contructor use `const` because you don't modify a.

```
 Array::Array(const Array& a)
 {
      mySize = a.mySize;
      myData = a.myData; //points to the same memory on the heap
 }
```

Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks, I have completely forgotten about delete[] operator. So, it must be the case, that delete[] is automatically called in a destructor.

Comment: @ВладиславБураков No, it is not automatically called.

Answer (score 3):

So... despite your claims, it turns out you **do** delete the array in the destructor, and the copy constructor is a shallow copy, so you get a double delete. Simple.

```
Array::~Array()
{
  delete[] myData;
}
```

Since this is a dynamic array, it should own the data, therefore you are right to delete in the destructor, but you need to "deep" copy in the copy constructor *and* the assignment operator. See [*the rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: re "need to deep copy" --  or reference count, or disable copying.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf OK, but I imagine a simple dynamic array should have simple data ownership semantics. And be copyable and assignable.

Answer (score 2):

Your copy is a shallow copy, so *IF* you have a destructor that frees memory, each object attempts to delete the same memory.

You don't *have* to do a shallow copy. You could write your own explicit copy constructor that copies the actual data into a newly allocated array.

I like Google's suggestion to [disable copy and assignment constructors](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Copy_Constructors#Copy_Constructors) and prefer explicit `CopyFrom()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

"double free" means that the same pointer has been given to `delete[]` twice. because in your destructor (presumably) it's `delete[]`-ed both in object `a` and `b`. practical solution: use `std::vector`, don’t mess with raw arrays etc. needlessly.

Comment: Oh, so maybe it is the case that delete[] is called automatically in destructor?

Comment: @ВладиславБураков: no it's not called automatically. presumably you, or whoever wrote code, put it there. it's difficult to say since you forgot to present that code.

Comment: No, I didn't present the rest, because I didn't override anything else than constructor

Comment: @ВладиславБураков: uhm, the information you have given is inconsistent with reality. could you please present a **complete** small example that exhibits the described behavior.

Comment: You've said *twice* now that you believe that `delete[]` is automatically called and you've been told that you're wrong. Can you post the *entire* code of the `Array` class, or a *complete, small example* that shows this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think your desctructors (from array 'a' and 'b') are trying to free the same memory (double free). Maybe  you should check you myData before freeing.